# gets.chomp method excercise in learn to program book

Tags: ruby

I am doing excercise 5.6 out of "Learn to Program" for a class.  I have the following:

```
    puts 'What\'s your first name?'
    first = gets.chomp
    puts 'What\'s your middle name?'
    middle = gets.chomp
    puts 'What\'s your last name?'
    last = gets.chomp
    puts 'Hello, Nice to meet you first middle last'
```

And I have tried the following:

```
     puts 'What is your first name?'
     first = gets.chomp
     puts 'What is your middle name?'
     middle = gets.chomp
     puts 'What is your last name?'
     last = gets.chomp
     puts 'Hello, Nice to meet you #{first} #{middle} #{last}'
```

When I get the last "puts" it won't get the first, middle and last name that I wrote in.  It says, "Hello, nice to meet you first, middle, last....Instead of Joe John Smith for example.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your help!  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

When using interpolation, use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`

Answer (score 3):

Strings within single quotes `'` do not replace variables with their values. Try using double quotes `"` like so:

```
puts "Hello, Nice to meet you #{first} #{middle} #{last}"
```

Single qoutes are nice if you want the string as you typed it, double quotes are useful when you want to replace variable names with their values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!  I just danced with happiness.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `%Q` to have the same effect as you get with double quotes `"`:

```
x = 12
puts %Q(I need #{x} pens)
# >> I need 12 pens
```

Comment: How are these operators called? Can I find an overview of all of them in the Ruby Docs?

Comment: @nTraum check here - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings